# Can you use .Contains(string) with a Select Case Statement?

Tags: vb.net, select-case

Is there anyway I can build a Select statement that uses the Contains function? Like this:

```
Select commentStr
    Case commentStr.Contains("10")
    Case commentStr.Contains("15")
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
Select Case True
    Case commentStr.Contains("10")
        'foo
    Case commentStr.Contains("15")
        'bar
End Select
```

Note that with this construct, a maximum of *one* `Case` will be executed.

(Also note that your C# friends *can't* do this with `switch`, which requires constant expressions in the `case` clauses :))

Comment: Perhaps because this syntax is equivalent to a series of `if` s in C# and being able to do the same with a `switch` would be superfluous. In C# `switch` statements are heavily optimized, and therefore only allow constant values. Don't know if it's the same in VB.

Comment: IMHO this is twisting `Select Case` too far. A series of `If` statements would be more readable, the same amount of code, and (I predict) just as performant.

Comment: @Matti you can twist **any** language and write unreadable code. Using expressions in `Case` statements can be brief **and** readable. The compiler could still detect compile-time constant values and optimise them heavily.

Comment: @MarkJ: And what advantage is there over a bunch of ifs?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen: You can write `Case X: CommandA` and it looks organic.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen: You can write case condition and case action in a single line, and it looks natural. Writing this in an If/ElseIf looks awkward, or maybe it's just me.

Comment: @MarkJ and @mattivirkkunen Series of `if` is NOT equivalent to `Select Case`. Perhaps you meant one `If - ElseIf -...` statement. In that case (and even for the series of `if`) I strongly disagree about readability; it's even vice versa in favor of `Select Case`. If can contain anything, while `Select Case` is firmly fixed to one variable and you can focus on the cases. The lines are pretty uniform (unlike `if-elseif`), very readable. Finally, it's not the same amount of code, there's extra element and operator at each `ElseIf` line.